# Switch Function Is Not Working Properly

Tags: functions, manipulate, convolution

I'd like to select between the Tent and Hat function to convolve, but my switch function produces an error.

I don't exactly need the initial plots. But I would like to plot the two that I select.

[image: Error Image]

```
(*Defining Tent Funtion*)

Tri[x_, wT_] := 
  Piecewise[{{(1/wT^2)*x + (1/wT), 
     0 > x > -wT}, {-(1/wT^2)*x + (1/wT), 0 < x < wT}}];

(*Defining Top Hat Funtion*)

Hat[x_, wH_] := 
  Piecewise[ {{(1/(2*wH)), 0 > x > -wH},  {(1/(2*wH)), 0 < x < wH}}];

 (*Defining Incline Funtion*)

(*Plotting & Manipulate Function*)
Manipulate[
 pT = Plot[Tri[x, wTent], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
   PlotRange -> All];
 pH = Plot[Hat[x, wH], {x, -10, 10}, PlotStyle -> LightGreen, 
   PlotRange -> All];
 Show[{pT, pH}, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> Medium],
 s1 = Switch[fx, "Tent Function", Tri[x + df, wTent], 
   "Top Hat Function", Hat[x + df, wH]];
 s2 = Switch[gx, "Tent Function", Tri[x + dg, wTent], 
   "Top Hat Function", Hat[x + dg, wH]];
 plotConv1 = 
  Plot[{s1, s2}, {x, -10, 10}, Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> All];
 {{wTent, 1, "Triangle Width"}, 0.1, 1},
 {{wH, 1, "Top Hat Width"}, 0.1, 1},
 {fx, {"Tent Function", "Top Hat Function"}},
 {{df, 0, "Shift fx"}, -5, 5},
 {gx, {"Tent Function", "Top Hat Function"}},
 {{dg, -5, "Shift fg"}, -10, 10}
 ]
```

Comment: Try putting the `Show` and the `plotConv` inside something like `GraphicsColumn`.

Comment: Immediately following `Show[ ... ]`, change comma to semicolon.  (The semicolon will turn red.)  Immediately following `plotConv1=Plot[ ... ]`, change semicolon to comma.

Answer (score 7):

```
(*Defining Tent Funtion*)
Tri[x_, wT_] :=
  Piecewise[{
    {(1/wT^2)*x + (1/wT), 0 > x > -wT},
    {-(1/wT^2)*x + (1/wT), 0 < x < wT}}];

(*Defining Top Hat Funtion*)
Hat[x_, wH_] :=
  Piecewise[{
    {(1/(2*wH)), 0 > x > -wH},
    {(1/(2*wH)), 0 < x < wH}}];

(*Plotting& Manipulate Function*)
Manipulate[
 s1 = Switch[fx, "Tent Function", Tri[x + df, wTent], 
   "Top Hat Function", Hat[x + df, wH]];
 s2 = Switch[gx, "Tent Function", Tri[x + dg, wTent], 
   "Top Hat Function", Hat[x + dg, wH]];
 Column[{
   Plot[
    {Tri[x, wTent], Hat[x, wH]},
    {x, -10, 10},
    PlotStyle -> {Blue, Green},
    Exclusions -> None,
    PlotRange -> All,
    ImageSize -> Medium],
   Plot[{s1, s2}, {x, -10, 10},
    Exclusions -> None,
    PlotRange -> All,
    ImageSize -> Medium]}],
 {{wTent, 1, "Triangle Width"}, 0.1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {{wH, 1, "Top Hat Width"}, 0.1, 1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {fx, {"Tent Function", "Top Hat Function"}}, 
 {{df, 0, "Shift fx"}, -5, 5, Appearance -> "Labeled"}, 
 {gx, {"Tent Function", "Top Hat Function"}}, 
 {{dg, -5, "Shift fg"}, -10, 10, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ControlPlacement -> Bottom]
```

[image]